# Unity3D embedded Mono with Unity

Tags: mono, unity-game-engine

I've seen plenty of examples of calling static methods in my Unity C# code using C++. I haven't however seen any examples of how to call a single instance's method using C++. i.e rather than

```
public static void SomeMethod(
{
}
```

I really want to do:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
}
```

I've managed to make the static implementation work by following some tutorials from  but would love to know if the bottom method is possible. I've tried to add a definition for searching a method in a class.

```
MonoMethod*     mono_method_desc_search_in_class (MonoMethodDesc *desc, MonoClass *klass);
```

But an implementation can't be found with the mono runtime that I was told to use from here: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/unity-native-plugins-os-x/

Any guidance or knowledge of whether it's possible or how to do it would be appreciated.

Edit:

One other question. If I search for a gameObject, could I then use that to access the instance?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what platform you're developing for, but for iOS there's the UnitySendMessage function. I believe there are similar implementations for other platforms.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html

> Calling C# / JavaScript back from native code
>
> Unity iOS supports limited native-to-managed callback functionality via UnitySendMessage:
>
> UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName1", "MethodName1", "Message to send");

The parameter must be a string, so I've used JSON to send more complex data.

Alternatively, everything that inherits from UnityEngine.Object has a GetInstanceID() method, which is guaranteed to be unique. Using this you could have a static method in C# that keeps a dictionary of recipient instances, and native code would always pass an integer ID to refer to the intended recipient.

```
static Dictionary<int, SomeClass> instanceDict = new Dictionary<...>();

void Awake() {
  instanceDict.Add(GetInstanceID(), this);
}

void OnDestroy() {
  instanceDict.Remove(GetInstanceID());
}

public static void SomeMethod(int recipientID, float someValue) {
  instanceDict[recipientID].SomeMethod(someValue);
}
```